# Graphlab on Windows 10: import error: No module named graphlab

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, importerror, graphlab

I'm trying to get started with Graphlab on my Windows 10-64 bit

I've succesfully followed the instruction listed here
https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html

Then I wrote a sample code:

```
>import graphlab
>from graphlab import SFrame

>sf=graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('../Dataset_movielens-latest-small/ratings.csv', delimiter=',', header= True, column_type_hints= list[int,int,float,int])

>sf.print_rows(100,4)
```

After that i've tried with my prompt to run it after activating conda environment but i get this.

```
>[gl-env] C:PATH>Toppop_graphlab.py
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:PATH\Toppop_graphlab.py", line 1, in <module>
>    import graphlab
>ImportError: No module named graphlab
```

Then i thought that my graphlab installation went wrong but i've tried this

```
>[gl-env] C:PATH>python
>Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
>Please check out: *links to continuum and anaconda that i can't post*
>>>> import graphlab
>>>>
```

As you can see it worked fine. I would like to just write a python script on notepad++ and run it like any other, what could i do?

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Install the dependencies and restart python. That might help.
 graphlab.get_dependencies()